# Can I disable Hyper Threading by setting processor affinity?

Tags: hyperthreading

I am developing on an Intel I7-6700  (4 cores, 8 logical HT processors) . Can I safely assume, if I set processor affinity to 1 processor (out of the 8 logical processor) , that Hyper Threading will never ever happen?

Unfortunately, I am unable to disable the HT from my very basic BIOS.

Thank you for taking time to answer.

Gary